# How to pass a page URL in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Im buiding a project in codeigniter..

I need to load a page in popup window

Popup window code is :

```
<div class='opener' data-addclose='true' data-balloon ='{ajax} grid-content.php?Action=0' style='position:relative; margin: auto; clear: both'>View</div>
```

grid-content.php is file in application\views\Adv_Product, how to pass this page url (grid-content.php) in my controller...??

I need to view this page contents in a popup.

How can I place this code in codeigniter...

Please help

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Do you have a controller called as **adv_product** and in it, we should have an index method inside it .. you can pass your **view file** in **controller** .. read CI documentation for more.  [Codeigniter Basic Concepts](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_basic_concepts.htm)

Comment: It's not normal view page. Its a php file, I need to view this page in a popup window, I wan't to pass this file in my controller....and that popup window is dynamically created, need to show the popup window when I'm clicking View button

Comment: yes .. view will be **.php** file and moreover, using above feature, you can pass your data as well in argument in controller function and check in your view file itself by passing data there ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : codeigniter does not provide to load directly view,

```
<div class='opener' data-addclose='true' data-balloon ='<?php echo base_url()?>/demo/popup_view/0' style='position:relative; margin: auto; clear: both'>View</div>
```

first to make a function inside your controller

Controller name: Demo.php

```
function popup_view()
{
   // if you send a parameter like action=0 

     $action=$this->uri->segment(3);

    if($action==0)
    {
       $data=array('action'=>'0');
    }
    else
    {
       $data=array('action'=>'');
    }

   $this->load->view('grid-content.php',$data);
}
```

Comment: ok, its working....but if $action value is 0 I need to place Add  form, if its value is 1 display the existing contents. Need to pass $action value in grid-content.php

Comment: data-balloon ='<?php base_url()?>/demo/popup_view/0' 0 your action value . if you like my answer so please upvote me.or accept my best answer

Comment: grid-contents.php file code 

if($action == 0){

// place an insert form
 
}

else {

// Display the existing contents
 
}

Comment: but its shows url path "base_url()/Adv_Product/popup_view/0", not showing any contents from grid-content.php

Comment: <?php echo base_url()?>Adv_Product/popup_view/0  use this code

Comment: popup window url passing Like this :  echo "<td><div  class='opener' data-addclose='true' data-balloon ='base_url()/Adv_Product/popup_view/0' style='position:relative; margin: auto; clear: both'>+</div></td>"
                popup window is working...but doesnot shows any contents from grid-content.php. Its shows only base_url()/Adv_Product/popup_view/0 this url path

Comment: do one thing .. enable **error reporting** in your **grid-content.php** and check any errors are there or not .. additionally, for now just **comment all php code** in this file and put static **hello** to check what happens.

Comment: try this rather - **<td><div class='opener' data-addclose='true' data-balloon ="<?php echo base_url()?>Adv_Product/popup_view/0" style='position:relative; margin: auto; clear: both'>+</div></td>**

Comment: Where **Adv_Product** should be your controller, **popup_view** should be your method of this controller and **0** should be your parameter of this particular method and in this particular controller of-course.

Comment: grid-content.php is working perfectly....but doesn't pass any value to grid-content.php

Comment: if you want to use any value so please put in data array and this data array to use in grid-content.php file